# Laravel hasMany relationship issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem about table relationship in models. when I try to add hasMany relation there is an error popping up.

> Call to undefined relationship [Plan100] on model [App\AllPlan].

This is the main table model `places`

```
protected $table = "places";

public $with = ["AllPlan"];

public function allplans()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\AllPlan");
}
```

And `AllPlan` table model

```
protected $table = "all_plans";

public function place()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Place");
}
```

No problem 'till here. I can see the `AllPlan` data inside the `Places` table on json response... But, the problem is popping up when I try to add `hasMany` relation into `AllPlan` table like below.

Now `AllPlan` table model looks like this.

```
protected $table = "all_plans";

 public $with = [
     "Plan100",
     "Plan90",
];

public function place()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Place");
}

public function plan()
{
    return $this->hasMany(
        "App\Plan100",
        "App\Plan90"
    );
}
```

And the `Plan100` table model look like this:

```
public function plan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\AllPlan");
}
```

But it's giving me an error. But I am not very sure where do I do wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Remove the ```$with``` variable from your model and try if it works.

Comment: if I delete this part `public $with = [
     "Plan100",
     "Plan90",
];` from `AllPlan` model then it doesn't insert the `100Plan` table in it? @AdlanArifZakaria

Comment: `$with` is an array of relationship names, not related models. in your case you named the relationship `plan` so you'd do `$with = [ 'plan' ]`. Also `hasMany` can only work with one related model and you're using two. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you are trying to create two new relations, but this can't be done inside one function. Create two functions and refactor your code like this:

```
public function plan100()
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\Plan100", 'foreign_key');
}

public function plan90()
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\Plan90", 'foreign_key');
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Happy coding!